difference way of fork lead in different result,why?
in MIT 6.828 homework shell
https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/homework/xv6-shell.html
I complement shell's pipe part , which enable me to execute some pipe command such as ls > temp and it works well. But when I execute ./my_sh < t.sh
//t.sh
ls > y
cat < y | sort | uniq | wc > y1
cat y1
rm y1
ls |  sort | uniq | wc
rm y

It gets error like:
     10      10      62
     10      10      62
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
cat: y1: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y1': No such file or directory
      9       9      60
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
cat: y1: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y1': No such file or directory
      9       9      60
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
cat: y1: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y1': No such file or directory
      9       9      60
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'y': No such file or directory

Here is my code:
case '|':
pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
// Your code here ...
//build pipe
if(pipe(p)== -1){
    perror("pipe");
    _exit(-1);
}
//pipe read at right
pid_t lpid,rpid;
if((lpid = fork1()) == 0){
    close(1);//0-1-2|stdin-stdout-stderr
    dup(p[1]);//let fd=1 point to write-side pipe
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    runcmd(pcmd->left);
}
wait(&r);
if((rpid = fork1()) == 0){
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);//let fd=0 point to read-side pipe
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    runcmd(pcmd->right);
}
close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
wait(&r);
break;

When I change way of fork , it works well
case '|':
pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
// Your code here ...
//build pipe
if(pipe(p)== -1){
    perror("pipe");
    _exit(-1);
}
//pipe read at right
pid_t lpid;
lpid = fork1();
if(lpid == 0){
    close(1);//0-1-2|stdin-stdout-stderr
    dup(p[1]);//let fd=1 point to write-side pipe
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    runcmd(pcmd->left);
}
else{
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);//let fd=0 point to read-side pipe
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    wait(&r);
    runcmd(pcmd->right);
}
break;

Why the first way gets error, and what is the difference between those two ways.

What is wait(&r); waiting for?
